# Reliable method of scraping page source i.e the tv at the beginning of each line?

Tags: html, css, xpath, web-scraping

When extracting data you can use CSS/xpaths.  But is there a similar or reliable method of doing this in the page source.

[www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Electronics-Televisions/zgbs/electronics/172659](https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Electronics-Televisions/zgbs/electronics/172659)

You could get the page source and then parse using Regex but probably not be reliable if for instance the tv did not load on the page. I have looked up various solutions but I have yet to find one that mentions getting every tv at start of each line (1, 4, 7 etc,, in source) or using a reliable method e.g Css/xpaths in source of a page.

What would is the golden standard of reliable method of doing what I am after?

Answer (score 0):

To get the page source you can use CURL if the page is rendered entirely on server side (most pages won't be), or headless chrome to get the actual DOM that will render in the browser (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome).

For scraping the content, I've used cheerio (https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) which will allow you to read in HTML to an object and then scrape your data off that using jQuery expressions. (Headless chrome allows you to execute JS on the pages you visit, so you don't necessarily need cheerio).

In your specific example you could get the TV on each line by combining the right class selectors to get the divs containing TV's, and using attribute selector with 'margin-left=0px' which would get first item on each line. That is obviously very much bound to structure of the page and will likely be broken by smallest of changes in the page source. (And not really any different from using xpaths. Still better than regex though)

With certain elements loading / not loading on the page (if that was what you meant by TV not being there), no  golden solutions that I know of, except allowing sufficient time for the page to load and handling your scraper failing gracefully.